# Modin - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ray'

Tags: python, pandas, modin, intel-modin

I'm trying to use Modin on Databricks and getting this error

I've tried both `pip install modin[all]` and `pip install modin[ray]`

Firstly, the installation takes 15 minutes, which is weird.

After installing, I'm doing

```
import modin.pandas as md
df = md.read_parquet('s3://path/to/file')
```

Getting this error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ray'

I have also tried setting `os.environ["MODIN_ENGINE"] = "ray"`

Comment: @Ramya Ravi - I don't think we need to add the [intel] tag when there's a specific tag like [intel-modin] that covers what makes the question Intel-related.  I follow the [intel] tag because sometimes people tag it instead of [x86] on [assembly] questions, but I don't want to see it tagged on questions where it doesn't need to be, like this or [intel-fortran] or other questions about software Intel happens to make.  The Intel collective already includes all the `[intel-whatever]` tags, or should.  Is that how you folks working for Intel(?) see the [intel] tag?

Answer (score 1):

I followed the below steps to install Modin using Ray execution engine.
Install Modin dependencies and Ray to run on Ray -

```
    pip install modin[ray]
```

Also, please customize your Ray environment for use in Modin using the below commands.

```
    import ray
    ray.init()
    import modin.pandas as pd
```

Please check out Intel Distribution of Modin (https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/oneapi/distribution-of-modin.html#gs.14j7r0) and Modin official page (https://modin.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for installation issues and to accelerate pandas workflow on Intel architectures.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
pip install ray
```

May be this will help you.